# How to correctly modify <HEAD> in Django-CMS for custom plugins?

Tags: django, plugins, django-cms

Django-CMS custom plugins and navigation extenders allow to create any content HTML in some part of the HTML . However I frequently have some JavaScripts required for some specific plugins, like a photo album viewer plugin that requires a JS in the .

My current solution is to let the user specify a specific template for that. I could do some checking in the [template render()](http://www.django-cms.org/en/documentation/2.0/custom_plugins/) to use a specific placeholder or use placeholder restrictions but that doesn't seem right: It's still in the "body" placeholder.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with including Javascript in the body - in fact, some consider it [best practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).